# robots.txt for disallowing Google to not to follow specific URLs

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have included *robots.txt* in the root directory of my application in order to tell Google bots that do not follow this `http://www.test.com/example.aspx?id=x&date=10/12/2014` URL or the URL with the same extension but different query string values. For that I have used following piece of code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /example.aspx/
```

But I found in the Webmaster Tools that Google is still following this page and has chached a number of URLs with the specified extension, is it something that query strings are creating problem because as far as I know that Google do not bother about query string, but just in case. Am I using it correctly or something else also needs to be done in order to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1):

Your instruction is wrong :

```
Disallow: /example.aspx/
```

This is blocking all URLs in the direcory `/example.aspx/`

If you want to block all URLs of the file `/example.aspx`, use this instruction:

```
Disallow: /example.aspx
```

You can test it with Google Webmaster Tools.